# How to fix "Picasso.get().load(mContext).into(imageView)"

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to first upload images to firebase then retrieving in in an activity(gallery) but getting a code error.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
       ImageUploaderAdapter uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
       holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
       Picasso.get().load(mContext).into(imageView)
            .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);
```

Error in code `Picasso.get().load(mContext).into(imageView)`

getting error

```
error: method get in class Picasso cannot be applied to given types;
        Picasso.get(mContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Picasso get() function is used in  this way :

```
Picasso.get().load("URL of image").into(imageView);
```

So you have to make changes in you code like this:

```
 Picasso.get().load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
        .into(imageView)            
        .fit()
        .centerCrop()
        .into(holder.imageView);
```

URL of image is needed to be inserted in function `load()` but you have inserted context

For more  information: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Hope this will  help you

Answer (score 0):

### Loading an Image from Url

We can load a remote image into any ImageView with:

```
String imageUri = "https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg";
ImageView ivBasicImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBasicImage);
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUri).into(ivBasicImage);
```

> If you are using the latest version of Picasso (2.71828) then remember
>   that with(context) methods is deprecated and is replaced with get()
>   method

```
String imageUri = "https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg";
ImageView ivBasicImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBasicImage);
Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(ivBasicImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to put the URL of the image in `load()` method.
**For example:**

```
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.get().load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.get().load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```